# How to check if Int value is @ColorRes or @ColorInt?

Tags: android

I have a method in which I can pass an int color value

```
fun setTint(color: Int) {

}
```

I can pass both `R.color.black` and `Color.BLACK` to it . In the method I want to check if it's `@ColorRes` or `@ColorInt` . How can I do it ?

Comment: You can also do something like fun setTint(@ColorRes color: Int)

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti No , I want to pass both , inside method I want to differentiate , like  `if( color is colorRes){ //do this}else {//do this )`  . What would be the condition

Comment: It is not possible.

Answer (score 6):

Android resource ids are 32-bit numbers while Android colors can be encoded as 32 bit integers or 64 bit longs.

So checking to see if the number is a valid color resource would be my approach first. If it is not a resource then it can be treated as an encoded color.

```
if(isColorResource(value)) Log.d(TAG,"Found color resource");
else Log.d(TAG,"Found color value");
```

```
public boolean isColorResource(int value) {
        try {
            ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), value, null);
            return true;
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }

    }
```